# how to make background like this (in link)? https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/s/bPavVmocgs

Tags: rendering, animation

[image: https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/s/bPavVmocgs]

https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/s/bPavVmocgs im beginner,if u know any similar tutorials on yt?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an *Input >Layer Weight (Facing* output) plugged into a *Converter > ColorRamp* (with all your colors) plugged into the *Output*. The *Layer Weight* uses the normals of your object, it will project a different color depending on how much the normal is parallel or perpendicular to your view:

[image]